# Python word substitution (replace values in curly braces with values from dict)

Tags: python, regex, substitution

my regex comprehension is awful and I need help making some substitutions. I've searched for similar questions but they're all a bit too different from my question.

Basically I have a dict of available parameters like so:

```
available_params = {'item1': 'dog', 'item2': 'cat', 'item3': 'horse'}
```

And I receive a string like this:

```
str = 'The {item3} and the {item2} kicked the {item1}.'
```

I just want to substitute the curly brace values with the corresponding dict value to get this:

> > The horse and the cat kicked the dog.

It seems like this should be very easy but I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass `dict` as argument to `str format` using `**`.One thing, please dont use `str` for variable name

```
>>>str.format(**available_params)
'The horse and the cat kicked the dog.'
```

Comment: Love this place, thanks for the quick answers. Thought it should be really simple. I do have another question though, what if the value received is not in the dict, will it cause an exception?

Comment: Yes.`**` is used to unpack `dict`

Answer (score 4):

Use the dict passing it to `str.format` and avoid using `str` as a variable name.

```
s = 'The {item3} and the {item2} kicked the {item1}.' 

s.format(**available_params)
```

Each placeholder name must match a key in the dict or you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks. And won't use str as my variable name, was just used as an example.